# iOS 7.1 NSString drawInRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawinrect

I have a code which worked just fine until I built my project with iOS 7.1. Before, the text correctly showed on PDF page.

```
[strSomeText drawInRect:rectForText withAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName, mutParagraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, colorRed, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]];
```

But now, everything in formatting dictionary is being disregarded. The PDF document shows black text of default font and size.

Thank you for responses.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using an `NSAttributedString` and find whether this works. I do not have a good reason as to why your code has stopped working, but try this:

```
//    obviously these variables are examples, keep whatever variables you are using
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"whatever_font" size:16.0f];
NSParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle];

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]};

NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:exampleString attributes:attributes];

[attributedString drawInRect];
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but unfortunately, the result is the same. That's strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);

[strSomeText drawInRect:rectForText withAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName, mutParagraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, colorRed, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]];

UIGraphicsPopContext();
```

Comment: It's been long, and looking at code, I don't see the difference, but pushing context was not part of solution. Anyway, thank you for your response.